# BootCamp cannot partition disk please run first aid error

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I'm trying to partition my disk and install windows 10 but I keep getting this error message:

> ”Your disk could not be partitioned. An error occurred while partitioning the disk. Please run First Aid from within Disk Utility to check and fix the error.”

I use a macbook pro retina 15 inch late 2013 with the latest Big Sur 16 GB RAM 2,4 GHz Intel Core i7

I tired running first aid several times, didn't work. I turned off auto time machine updates, turned off file vault, tried starting in single user mode, internet recovery mode and ran some `fsck_apfs` and `diskutil` codes that I saw on some previous forum posts.

Years ago when I first bought this computer, I have installed windows xp and windows 7 with bootcamp several times without a problem but eventually removed them. After removing windows I erased my whole drive maybe couple of times. I also checked that my disk has only 1 partition right now but nothing worked.

The only 2 things I need windows for are Revit and Sims 4 (the version I bought only works on windows).

I'm not very knowledgeable about these stuff but usually I just try doing what I can find on forums and somehow make it work. This time nothing on forums solved my problem, I hope you can help me. Thanks!